# Checking if a x,y position is within a dynamically generated Ellipse

Tags: c#, random, position, ellipse

I'm trying to calculate whether or not a specific X,Y position lies within an ellipse in C#.

The available variables to work with are:
X (the X I want to check)
Y (the Y I want to check)
The width of the ellipse
The height of the ellipse
The x-center of the ellipse (as the ellipse is drawn somehwere on a screen, it has to be calculated).
The y-center of the ellipse (again, random position, so this had to be calculated.

So far I tried basic mathematics, but those wouldn't get me as far as I needed.

Comment: Why basic math failed? There is ellipse equation to which you should be able to use you x and y to calculate if the point is on or inside of ellipse or outside of it. Why is that a problem?

Comment: It failed becuase of human error of course. A misscalculation in determining where the ellipse was on the screen. 
I feel such an idiot sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the ellipse horizontal, or rotated?

For horizontal ellipse with center `(xc,yc)` and radii `rx` and `ry` all the points inside obey the equation

```
((x-xc)/rx)^2 + ((y-yc)/ry)^2 <= 1
```

So just check your point `(x,y)` against the equation above.

Comment: I tried this equation before and it didn't work. Turned out to be a mistake on my part... Miss placement of a couple of brackets in the calculation of the position of the ellipse.

Comment: So it works now, right?

Comment: Yes, it does work now :)

Answer (score 1):

Try `yourEllipse.RenderedGeometry.StrokeContains(Pen pen, Point point)` method